# AWS EC2 Windows SSH Help - Chmod 400 (RSA Key).pem Not Working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, edx

Thank you all who use their time to help others. Thank you in advance.

I am taking a class on EDX for Linux command line. I have attached the instructions I have followed to set up Red hat using Windows 10. But the SSH for isn't working it says that RSA Key not found. (Attachment didn't work)

I paste it here

"The recommended way to access your Red Hat Enterprise Linux cloud instance for this course is
to use Secure Shell (ssh​) to get an interactive shell on the system.
Step 1: Getting SSH
If you are using macOS or Linux: The OpenSSH command (ssh​) should already be installed on
your computer. Start a terminal program to get a shell, and proceed to the next step.
If you are using Microsoft Windows, you will need to get an SSH client as follows:
● Option 1: Download Git for Windows​ from https://git-scm.com/download/win and install
it using the default settings. When it is installed, right-click on your desktop (not an icon
or a file) and select Git Bash Here​ to open a Git Bash​ command prompt. An SSH client is
provided with Git Bash​ and you can continue with Step 2.
● Option 2: If you have the PuTTY client, which can be downloaded from
http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/, and you are familiar with that
tool, you can use that to connect to your instance. AWS provides a tutorial on this at
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/putty.html.
Step 2: Connecting to your instance with SSH
From the Amazon EC2 console, in the left-side menu under INSTANCES​, click Instances​ to
display a list of the instances you have running. This is probably just the one you set up for this
course. Select its checkbox and click Connect:"

Also, I have another PC I built running on Ubuntu. Can I use that PC with the RSA by logging into AWS account if there is no solution.

I have researched this question and I am stuck here trying to find a solution so I can start class.

Comment: Can you paste the command you are using to log into the ec2 box and the exact your are getting? You either are missing .pem file parameter in ssh command or are having very open permission for that file.

Comment: Here is when I was connected and running the AWS instance  
Mar Roble@DESKTOP-3O814V1 MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ chmod 400 Mykeypair.pem
chmod: cannot access 'Mykeypair.pem'$'\302\203\302\203': No such file or directory

Mar Roble@DESKTOP-3O814V1 MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$ chmod 400 Mykeypair.pem
chmod: cannot access 'Mykeypair.pem': No such file or directory

Mar Roble@DESKTOP-3O814V1 MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$

Comment: Thank you Vishal.  I am going to install Virtual Machine and use Linux based OS.